# How to hide edit/create button on form by conditions?

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-8

I'm a new Odoo developer and I need to hide the edit button when my form is entering a custom state, I need this because of a security problem.

This code in XML does not work when I try to give an attribute to the form.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="pesan_form_view">
    <field name="name">pesan_service_form</field>
    <field name="model">pesan.service</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Booking Service" attrs="{edit:'false':[('state','in','baru')]}">
    <!-- structure of form -->
</record>
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: You can set all fields as readonly when state is 'baru'..

Answer (score 1):

qWeb conditions doesn't work for `FormView`.

You can check it here(*path_to_odoo/addons/web/static/src/js/framework/view.js*):

```
 /**
  * Return whether the user can perform the action ('create', 'edit', 'delete') in this view.
  * An action is disabled by setting the corresponding attribute in the view's main element,
  * like: <form string="" create="false" edit="false" delete="false">
  */
  is_action_enabled: function(action) {
      var attrs = this.fields_view.arch.attrs;
      return (action in attrs) ? JSON.parse(attrs[action]) : true;
  },
```

This method calls from template `FormView.buttons` in *path_to_odoo/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml*:

```
<button t-if="widget.is_action_enabled('edit')"
    type="button"
    class="oe_form_button_edit btn btn-default btn-sm" accesskey="E">
    Edit
</button>
```

These problems are solved in Odoo with the help of rules(`ir.rule` object of Odoo)

You can find and edit rules in GUI here: Settings(top menu) -> Security(left menu) -> Access Rules(left menu). Use **admin user in debug mode** for this.

At the same you can add some rules to `data.xml` of your module for import. They will be added when you install or update module.

Be careful! [Record rules do not apply to the Administrator user](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/security.html#record-rules).

At the same you can try to expand widget `FormView`.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="pesan_form_view">
    <field name="name">pesan_service_form</field>
    <field name="model">pesan.service</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Booking Service" attrs="{'edit': [('state', 'in', ['baru'])]}">
    <!-- structure of form -->
</record>
```

Comment: I don't know about v8, but this solution doesn't work on v9.

Comment: Well I have checked this in odoo9. Please provide your used code for more details.

Comment: I checked **name** of some object. `<form attrs="{'edit': [('name', 'not in', ['name1', 'name2'])]}">`. It did not help. *name* it is `Char` field. Maybe this solution works only with `field.Select`.

Comment: When I inherit some view this solution doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong? `<xpath expr='(//form)' position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="attrs">{'edit': [('state', 'in', ['open'])]}</attribute>
                </xpath>`